# C Stack Manager Project: file I/O with syscalls problems

Tags: c, io, linked-list, system-calls

I'm currently working on a c library that emulates a stack(using a linked list).

The stack has to be able to manage any data Type.

It also has to be able to write it's contents to a file and then retrieve them. Here is where I'm having problems. When I compare the original stack to the one I stored in the file data is not the same.

Here is the code:

**writeRead.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "stack.h"

#define NODES 3

struct my_data {
    int val;
    char name[60];
};

int main() {
    struct my_stack *s1, *fs1;
    struct my_data *data, *data1, *data2;

    // Initialize Stack
    s1 = my_stack_init(sizeof(struct my_data));
    // Initialize data and push to stack
    for (int i = 0; i < NODES; i++) {
        data = malloc(sizeof(struct my_data)); // We must allocate static memory
        data->val = i;
        sprintf(data->name, "Value %d", i);
        if (my_stack_push(s1, data)) {
            puts("Error in my_stack_push()");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("New node in s1: (%d, %s)\n", data->val, data->name);
    }

    // Write Stack to file
    if (my_stack_write(s1, "/tmp/my_stack.data") == -1) {
        puts("Error in my_stack_write (s1)");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Read Stack from file
    fs1 = my_stack_read("/tmp/my_stack.data");
    if (!fs1) {
        puts("Error in my_stack_read (fs1)");
        exit(1);
    }


    // Compare data of stack s1 (memory) and fs1 (file)
    while ((data1 = my_stack_pop(s1))) {
        printf("FS1 len. %d\n",my_stack_len(fs1));
        data2 = my_stack_pop(fs1);
        printf("Node of s1: (%d, %s)\t", data1->val, data1->name);
        printf("Node of fs1: (%d, %s)\n", data2->val, data2->name);
        if (!data2 || data1->val != data2->val || my_strcmp(data1->name, data2->name)) {
            printf("Data in s1 and fs1 are not the same.\n (data1->val: %d <> data2->val: %d) o (data1->name: %s <> data2->name: "
                   "%s)\n",
                   data1->val, data2->val, data1->name, data2->name);
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    return 0;


}
```

**stack.h**

```
#include <fcntl.h>     /* Modos de apertura de función open()*/
#include <stdlib.h>    /* Funciones malloc(), free(), y valor NULL */
#include <sys/stat.h>  /* Permisos función open() */
#include <sys/types.h> /* Definiciones de tipos de datos como size_t*/
#include <unistd.h>    /* Funciones read(), write(), close()*/

struct my_stack_node {
    void *data;
    struct my_stack_node *next;
};

struct my_stack {
    int size;
    struct my_stack_node *first;
};

int my_strcmp(const char *str1, const char *str2);
struct my_stack *my_stack_init(int size);
int my_stack_push(struct my_stack *stack, void *data);
void *my_stack_pop(struct my_stack *stack);
int my_stack_len(struct my_stack *stack);
struct my_stack *my_stack_read(char *filename);
int my_stack_write(struct my_stack *stack, char *filename);
int my_stack_purge(struct my_stack *stack);
```

**stack.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stack.h"

int my_strcmp(const char *str1, const char *str2) {
    int restultatCmp = *str1++ - *str2++;
    //printf("ResultatCmp : %d \n", restultatCmp);
    while(*str1++ && *str2++ && restultatCmp == 0) {
        restultatCmp = *str1 - *str2;
    }
    return restultatCmp;
}

struct my_stack *my_stack_init(int dataSize) {
    struct my_stack *stack = malloc(sizeof(struct my_stack));
    stack -> first = NULL;
    stack -> size = dataSize;
    return stack;
}

int my_stack_push(struct my_stack *stack, void *dataIn) {
    struct my_stack_node *nodeToPush;
    nodeToPush = malloc(sizeof(struct my_stack_node));

    if(stack == NULL && sizeof(dataIn)> 0){
        printf("Null Stack or data size error.\n");
        //la pila debe existir
        return -1;
    } 
    else {
        nodeToPush -> data = dataIn;
        if(stack -> first == NULL) {
            nodeToPush -> next = NULL;
            stack -> first = nodeToPush;

        }
        else {
            nodeToPush -> next = stack -> first;
            stack -> first = nodeToPush;  
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void *my_stack_pop(struct my_stack *stack) {
    if(stack -> first == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    struct my_stack_node *nodeToDelete = stack -> first;
    void *data = nodeToDelete -> data;
    stack -> first = nodeToDelete -> next;
    free(nodeToDelete);

    return data; 
}

int my_stack_len(struct my_stack *stack) {
    int numNodes = 0;
    struct my_stack_node *currentElement = stack -> first;
    while(currentElement != NULL) {
        numNodes++;
        currentElement = currentElement ->next;
    }
    return numNodes;
}

void recursiveWrite(struct my_stack_node *nodo, int fileDesc, int sizeData) {
    if(nodo ->next != NULL) recursiveWrite(nodo -> next,fileDesc,sizeData);
    if(write(fileDesc, nodo -> data, sizeData)== -1){
        printf("Error de escritura\n");
        return;// error escritura.
    }
}

int my_stack_write(struct my_stack *stack, char *filename) {
    struct my_stack_node *currentNode = stack -> first;
    int fileDesc = open(filename, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    if(fileDesc == -1) {
        return -1; // Error open();
    }
    if(write(fileDesc, &stack -> size, sizeof(stack -> size)) == -1){
        return -1; // Error write();
    }
    int sizeData = stack -> size;
    recursiveWrite(currentNode,fileDesc,sizeData);
    close(fileDesc);

    return my_stack_len(stack);
}

struct my_stack *my_stack_read(char *filename) {
    int fileDesc = open(filename, O_RDONLY, S_IRUSR);
    if(fileDesc == -1) {
        return NULL; // Error open();
    }
    char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(int));
    int readBytes;
    if((readBytes = read(fileDesc, buffer, sizeof(int))) == -1){
        printf("Error reading data size.\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    int dataSize = 0;
    dataSize = (int) *buffer; // parse data Size from buffer.
    struct my_stack *stack; 
    stack = malloc(sizeof(struct my_stack));
    stack = my_stack_init(dataSize); // initialize Stack
    buffer = realloc(buffer, stack -> size);
    if(buffer == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    else{
        while(read(fileDesc, buffer, stack -> size) > 0) {
            if((my_stack_push(stack,buffer))== -1){
                printf("Error en my_stack_read: Push error.\n");
                return NULL;
            }

        }
    close(fileDesc);
    return stack;
    }   
}
```

Sorry for the large code I tried to simplify the example as much as I could.

**Output:**

```
New node in s1: (0, Value 0)
New node in s1: (1, Value 1)
New node in s1: (2, Value 2)
FS1 len. 3
Node of s1: (2, Value 2)        Node of fs1: (2, Value 2)
FS1 len. 2
Node of s1: (1, Value 1)        Node of fs1: (2, Value 2)
Data in s1 and fs1 are not the same.
 (data1->val: 1 <> data2->val: 2) o (data1->name: Value 1 <> data2->name: Value 2)
```

**Expected output:**

```
New node in s1: (0, Value 0)
New node in s1: (1, Value 1)
New node in s1: (2, Value 2)
FS1 len. 3
Node of s1: (2, Value 2)        Node of fs1: (2, Value 2)
FS1 len. 2
Node of s1: (1, Value 1)        Node of fs1: (1, Value 1)
FS1 len. 1
Node of s1: (0, Value 0)        Node of fs1: (0, Value 0)
```

I'm almost sure that the file writting is correct. Checked with a hex editor and should be correct.

So my guesses are that my fault is at the reading of the file.

Forgot to mention that a restriction of the project is that system calls for I/O are mandatory.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit1:**

Changed *my_stack_read() as @AndrewHenle suggested, the output is still not the expected.

```
struct my_stack *my_stack_read(char *filename) {
    int fileDesc = open(filename, O_RDONLY, S_IRUSR);
    if(fileDesc == -1) {
        return NULL; // Error open();
    }
    char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(int));
    ssize_t readBytes;
    readBytes = read(fileDesc, buffer, sizeof(int));
    if(readBytes == -1) {
        return NULL;
    }
    int dataSize = 0;
    dataSize = (int) *buffer; // parse data Size from buffer.
    struct my_stack *stack; 
    stack = malloc(sizeof(struct my_stack));
    stack = my_stack_init(dataSize); // initialize Stack
    buffer = realloc(buffer, stack -> size);
    if(buffer == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    else{
        while(read(fileDesc, buffer, stack -> size) > 0) {
            int push = my_stack_push(stack,buffer);
            if(push == -1){
                printf("Error en my_stack_read: Push error.\n");
                return NULL;
            }

        }
    close(fileDesc);
    return stack;
    }
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: First, `read()` and `write()` return `ssize_t` not `int`.  Second, IMO `if((readBytes = read(fileDesc, buffer, sizeof(int))) == -1)...` is an absolutely horrendous way to make function calls, especially for functions such as `read()` and `write()` which can return partial success.  Don't try to stuff so much into a line of code that you can't handle function call results properly.  You get no bonus points for using a smaller number of lines - in fact, you make your code *harder* to understand when you overdo the stuffing like that.

Comment: Thank for your the fast answers! I'll try to change the code with your suggestions @AndrewHenle. Mind that this is for learning purposes and I'm fairly new to some concepts. Very much appreciated!

Comment: @melpomene Thanks for the post. I think I try to do almost everything that it says. I've been working quite a lot in this project and I tried debugging with gdb and valgrind (although this last one still is difficult). I also tried different tests. My post is a simplification of a bigger one. I used also online tools like Ctutor to visualize the code execution. I didn't want to enlarge the post by pointing all of this. I know my problem may seem trivial but I didn't post all of this without having done research or tried all that is in my hands. I appreciate your intentions though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

I found my error in ***my_stack_read:**

```
while(read(fileDesc, buffer, stack -> size) > 0) {
        int push = my_stack_push(stack,buffer);
        if(push == -1){
            printf("Error en my_stack_read: Push error.\n");
            return NULL;
        }
        buffer = malloc(stack -> size);
    }
```

**buffer = malloc(stack -> size);** I had allocated the memory outside the for loop, and I didn't allocate for the subsequent reads.

I thought the read would use same direction overwritting it's content but it seems this is not possible.

Could anyone explain the reason?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing to the stack in a recursive manner. The function below writes the **last** element of the stack to the file first. It writes the data reversed.

```
void recursiveWrite(struct my_stack_node *nodo, int fileDesc, int sizeData) {
    if(nodo ->next != NULL) recursiveWrite(nodo -> next,fileDesc,sizeData);
    if(write(fileDesc, nodo -> data, sizeData)== -1){
        printf("Error de escritura\n");
        return;// error escritura.
    }
}
```

To write the data in correct order, you should call the recursive function after the `write` function. I have also changed the `write` function to remove it from the `if` condition.

```
void recursiveWrite(struct my_stack_node *nodo, int fileDesc, int sizeData) {
   int ret;
   ret = write(fileDesc, nodo -> data, sizeData); 
   if(ret == -1){
        printf("Error de escritura\n");
        return;// error escritura.
    }
    if(nodo ->next != NULL) recursiveWrite(nodo -> next,fileDesc,sizeData);
}
```

Comment: Hello @RishikeshRaje, yes this is done on purpose. When I reconstruct the Stack with push method it will add the nodes in reverse order so it will be exactly as the original stack. Thank you very much! I'll try your code!